# DropDown box notepad in c# how would i load text file on button press?

Tags: c#

i'm really new to programming and wanting to create a notepad program with multiple drop down menus for dnd. The idea is that i would have a side bar that has several Drop Down boxes for each category like World, Characters, Classes, Races, etc. When i click on one a list of buttons drop down that each open to a Text box with different info inside.

Right now i'm trying to figure out is for each of those buttons to open a text box like notepad that i can use to write down info on different topics in that category, and when i save it and click on a different button it opens a different text box for that button and if i go back to the previous button all of the text i wrote before will still be there even if i close the app. Any Tips on how i should go about this?

Crappy Ex.....

--Category: world--

--Button 1

--Button 2

(imagine i open the Text box for Button 1 and write down some stuff, and then i switch to button 2 and write down some stuff there. I then go back to button 1 and the text i wrote before for button 1 is still there. When i close the app and reopen both button's text boxes still contain the stuff i wrote in them from before.)

Comment: Can you clarify your statement a bit. I'm not following what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Sorry bout that.So imagine i have an app with a side bar that contains drop down boxes. These drop down boxes have a title and when you click on one a sub menu drops down with a list of buttons. what i would want is for each of those buttons to open a text box like notepad that i can use to write down info on different topics, and when i save it and click on a different button it opens a different text box for that button and if i go back to the previous button all of the text i wrote before will still be there even if i close the app. idk if that helps